# How to initialize a label in ios with array content?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am developing an quiz app. I want the label to be appeared  with a question that is in an array when i run the application.I have created the UIlable. I used init method which does not work. My codes are following

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,assign)int currentQuestionIndex;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSArray *questions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //fill two array
        self.questions =@[@"Who is the president of US?",@"What is 7 + 7?",@"What is the capital of Vermont?"];
        }
    //return the address of new object
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender
{
    // Step to the next question
    self.currentQuestionIndex++;

    // Am I pas the last question?
    if (self.currentQuestionIndex == [self.questions count]) {

        // Go back to the first question
        self.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    }

    // Get the string at the index in the questions array
    NSString *question = self.questions[self.currentQuestionIndex];

    // Display the string in the question label
    self.questionLabel.text = question;
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Try to move the code `self.questions = ...` to `viewDidLoad`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the init of the questions to `awakeFromNib()` or `viewDidLoad()` because storyboard do not use `initWithNibName`

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
       #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController ()
    @property(nonatomic,assign)int currentQuestionIndex;
    @property(nonatomic,copy)NSArray *questions;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
    @end

    @implementation ViewController



    - (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender
    {
        [self showQuestion];
        }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.questions =@[@"Who is the president of US?",@"What is 7 + 7?",@"What is the capital of Vermont?"];

self.currentQuestionIndex= 0;
[self showQuestion];
        }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

-(void)showQuestion{
// Step to the next question


        // Get the string at the index in the questions array
        NSString *question = self.questions[self.currentQuestionIndex];

        // Display the string in the question label
        self.questionLabel.text = question;

 self.currentQuestionIndex++;

        // Am I pas the last question?
        if (self.currentQuestionIndex == [self.questions count]) {

            // Go back to the first question
            self.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        }


}

    @end
```

Comment: Thank you  guys .Now i understood.